# onTapNotification on Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I have the app running in the background, I can use onMessageOpenedApp to call a function when tapping a notification, and the event that fires the function is not the tap on notification but the open app event.

I need to be able to call a function when tapping a notification when the app is in the foreground.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase_messaging: ^11.2.4 and flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.5

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message)
```

_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler In your method, you can issue local notification if a message comes.

Comment: Yes but this is not called on the on Tap event, it is called when the notification arrives, right?

Comment: Yes. When the push notification comes, the push notification will not appear in the status bar because the application is in the foreground. We catch the push to appear and show it as a local notification.

Comment: No, that is not true, you can have notifications with the app in the foreground if you want to